# Pull all data via API from successfactors

Tags: rest, pagination, sap-successfactors

All,

I am trying to pull all data from successfactors using oData API but it give only 1000 rows at a time

How to pull all the data at a time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OData API can return a maximum number of 1000 records in a single page.
To get the next page of your dataset, you have to call the __next API (which carries a skip token) from previous response. Repeat this action until you get all data via API.